# CSS with only ids and classes - is this the right way?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I think I could write pretty much all my CSS styles just by using ids and classes.
No complicated selectors. No complicated rules.

Besides, the following holds:

> *The sad truth about CSS3 selectors is that they really shouldn’t be used at all if you care about page performance. Decorating your markup with classes and ids and matching purely on those while avoiding all uses of sibling, descendant and child selectors will actually make a page perform significantly better in all browsers.*

and I care ABOUT page performance...

SEE HERE FOR fURTHER INFO:
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: "and I care ABOUT page performance..." Then stop caring.

Comment: I tend to only use classes and ID's as I have to make websites work in old browsers, which do not support nice selectors.

Comment: Why are you asking a question when you already seem determined?

Comment: @Robert because although I am 'determined' I might be wrong. And I would rather know

Comment: @BoltClock Performance is incredibly important in websites. It's silly to say: "stop caring"

Comment: @chacko: Are special CSS combinators alone going to cause any browser to render your website even 1 second slower? If you really care, do your own benchmarks and see for yourself. There are many, many other factors that affect a browser's rendering speed, CSS parsing being a very minute factor.

Comment: The only reason why you should avoid advanced CSS selectors is for browser compatibility (think IE). The topic of premature optimization has been **done to death**. Don't think about performance until you are sure that CSS parsing is the only thing left that's making browsers render your page slowly, which, I guarantee you, will **never happen**. Modern browsers have incredibly quick rendering engines that are only limited by the speed at which the actual HTML and CSS gets downloaded. If you find your pages are rendering slowly, blame network latency and perhaps JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Oversimplification  may mean worse maintainability

Sometimes setting it all in **just** classes and IDs isn't enough. Depends whether you also control your markup. If you do you can do that, but I suppose it will become a PITA when you'd want to change things. Finding your way around with IDs is significantly less verbose than descendant selectors.

```
#SomeButton { ... } // who the hell am I
```

vs.

```
.editor .action-button { ... } // oh that's who!
```

Don't use too strong restrictions = don't oversimplify things because they will get complicates on the long run (they'll turn against you). Trade some for the benefit of maintainability. It could as well mean that you would introduce lots of repeated styles. So be care full with simplification.

If backward compatibility is also an issue here, then restrict yourself to descendant selectors only and don't use too deep relationships if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's the right way for speed and backward compatibility. These are important.

However, it's the wrong way for maintainability (someone else continuing your work) and scalability (many sites, subdomains, pages, widgets, sub-themes).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. If you can create some generic style rules for certain elements, it can save you a lot of time and creating repetitive code. For instance if you write

```
.div-element-1{font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12px;}
.div-element-2{font-family:Helvetica; font-size:14px;}
.div-element-3{font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px;}
```

instead you can write:

```
div{font-family:Helvetica;}
```

and that will get applied to all divs and keeping you from writing your font over and over and over